# How to create a dummy variable

Tags: spss

I'm working in a project that uses the IBM SPSS but I had some problems to set a dummy variable(binary variable).The process to get the variable is following : Consider an any variable(width for example), to get the dummy variable, we need
to sort this variable in the decreasing way; The next step is  make a somatory of the cases until a limit, the cases before the limit receive the value 1 in the dummy variable the other values receive 0.

Comment: Please provide an example data set showing the prior data and what you want in the end. When you say sort, do you mean sort variables, or sort cases?

Comment: Hey friend thanks for attemption, I'll put some images that probably will answer all your questions.

*here we have the general dataset
 [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8823/jsemcz.png)


*here I'm explaining about how to set the dummy

[link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img921/9257/pROEVB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is rather vague. And the critical value you give in the printscreen should be 2.009 in stead of 20.09?
But I think you mean the following.
When using syntax, use:

```
compute newdummyvariable eq (ABr gt 2.009477106).
```

To check if it's okay:

```
fre newdummyvariable.
```

### UPDATE:

In order to compute a dummy based on the cumulative sum, the answer is as follows: 
If your critical value is predetermined, the fastest way is to sort in decending order, and to use the command create with `csum()` to compute an extra variable which I called `ABr_cumul`. This one, you use to compute the `newdummyvariable`. As follows:

```
sort cases by ABr (d).  
create ABr_cumul = csum(VAR00001). 
compute newdummyvariable = (ABr_cumul le 20.094771061766488).  
fre newdummyvariable.
```

Comment: Hey friend, thanks for attention. I'm sorry for the confusion, actually the critical value is 20.09(I made the mistake because here in Brazil we use the comma to separate the decimal values). I'll try the steps that you have recommended.

Comment: In short: you don't have to sort the file in order to create a new variable, if you use a conditional statement within `compute`. Be sure to check if you need `gt` (greater than) or `ge` (greater than, or equals).

Comment: Hey friend, your solution is all right. But I didn't understand why the value is 2.009477106 in stead of 20,094771061766488. I would like to say thanks for your help, but I need to understand this number notation.

Comment: Sorry. Just put in your own critical value! And make sure you use a dot as decimal separator. So that would be 20.094771061766488

I used a different number, because I did not see any cases with figures exceeding 20, so I thought you might have made a typing error.

Also, can you accept my answer by clicking on the arrow upwards next to the answer?

Comment: Man, I've bad news... How I've said the limit value is obtained by adding the values of each case(this is the reason of the critical value 20,094771061766488(8,950906386026778+3,259132734585927+2,914761143864676+2,639263871287674+2.330706926001433) ) .

To be more exact, I need to atribute value 1 to the dummy variable until the line where the summing of the Abr values is equal to 18149. Sorry for the confusion again.

Comment: Aha, you are looking for the cumulative sum? In that case, and if your critical value is predetermined, the fastest way is to sort in decending order, and to use the command `create` with `csum()` to compute an extra variable which I called `ABr_cumul`. This one, you use to compute the `newdummyvariable`. As follows:

`sort cases by ABr (d).`  
`create ABr_cumul = csum(VAR00001).`   
`compute newdummyvariable = (ABr_cumul le 20.094771061766488).`  
`fre newdummyvariable.`  
Does this work?

Comment: I'll put this in the original answer, so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

the dummy comes from the sum of all cases, after decreasing order raqueados when cases of a variable representing 50% of the variable t0tal, these cases receive 1 and the other 0 ...